# Android studio navigation drawer error

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I am getting an errot when I opened android studio in navigation drawer activity. The error says

> Rendering problem
>   Exception raised during rendering

and the following is the error detail:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to locate mode 0
at android.view.DisplayInfo.findMode(DisplayInfo.java:458)
at android.view.DisplayInfo.getMode(DisplayInfo.java:445)
at android.view.Display.getRefreshRate(Display.java:648)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onAttachedToWindow(RecyclerView.java:2392)
at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:15392)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2953)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2960)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2960)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2960)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2960)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2960)
at android.view.AttachInfo_Accessor.setAttachInfo(AttachInfo_Accessor.java:42)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:333)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:429)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:389)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:548)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:533)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:966)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:533)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$70(RenderTask.java:659)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issues before. Usually cleaning and rebuilding the project or updating android studio or/and the SDK fixes the issue.